# Create a page and redirect to it after

Tags: wp-redirect

The following function is called in an ajax callback. When I click a button in the front end it should create a new page and immediately redirect to it.
The page is created, however no redirect happens. Can someone help please? Thanks.

```
function kb_addBlankPage() {
  $post_details = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Blank Page',
  'post_content'  => 'Content of the page',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_type' => 'page'
   );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_details);
    $url = get_permalink($post_id);
    wp_redirect($url); 
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Output the $url value before the wp_redirect to see what it actually is:

die("url is " . $url):

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that variable $url has the new page URL (e.g. https://domain.com/blank-page) however still no redirect. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that the $url value is in the proper format: https://www.domain.com/page . The 'https://" part is important. I'd also use wp_safe_redirect to ensure a 'safe' URL (see the docs).  In addition, look at your error.log file to ensure you aren't getting any 'headers already sent' errors, which would cause the redirect to fail. If possible, use a filter to perform the redirect - filter should happen before any output.